# Image view that can zoom when pressed, and swipe to show other photos

Tags: android, android-image, android-glide

I tried glide slider but doesn't work like I want it. This is the link of a gif showing what I want to achieve. I need it to be:
fill the screen when clicked
Swipe-able
shrink to original size when back button is pressed
Simple transition from image to image, nothing fancy.
and compatible with Glide v4(any version would work tho)
Please help.
[an example](https://media.giphy.com/media/1n8AELgggI4WQ1nR8q/giphy.gif)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used PhotoView, a library, works like a charm.